# Can't remove custom Odoo snippet

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I created a custom snippet on Odoo 8. Basically it is a slideshow component from uikit that I want to insert as a content inside *.row* bootstrap elements, that is, inside another snippet. Below is my code. However, when I try to remove the slideshow snippet via the Website builder (not the HTML Editor), it still appears after saving. The only way I can remove it is by editing it from the HTML Editor. What could be wrong?

```xml
<openerp>
    <data>

        <template id="snippet_blocks" inherit_id="website.snippets" name="Snippet Blocks">
            <!-- Create new group called Essentials-->
            <xpath expr="div[1]/ul" position="inside">
                <li>
                    <a href="#snippet_essentials" data-toggle="tab">Essentials</a>
                </li>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="div/div/div[@id='snippet_effect']" position="after">
                <div id="snippet_essentials" class="tab-pane">
                    <!-- Slideshow Snippet -->
                    <div class="we_snippet">
                        <!-- Snippet thumnail-->
                        <div class="oe_snippet_thumbnail">
                            <img class="oe_snippet_thumbnail_img"
                                 src="/sci5_website_essentials/static/img/slideshow.png"/>
                            <span class="oe_snippet_thumbnail_title">Slideshow</span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Snippet code to insert-->
                        <div class="oe_snippet_body we_slideshow col-md-8 mb128">
                            <t t-call="sci5_website_essentials.snippet_slideshow"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </template>

        <template id="snippet_options" inherit_id="website.snippet_options" name="Snippet Options">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <div data-snippet-option-id='snippet_essentials'
                     data-selector=".we_slideshow"
                     data-selector-siblings=".row > [class*='col-md-']"
                     data-selector-children=".row">
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </template>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

This is the snippet body:

```xml
<openerp>
    <data>

        <template id="snippet_slideshow" name="Slideshow">
            <section class="snippet_slideshow">
                <ul class="uk-slideshow" data-uk-slideshow="{autoplay:true}">
                    <li>
                        <img src="/website/static/src/img/library/business_conference.jpg"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="/website/static/src/img/library/gears.png"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="/website/static/src/img/library/engineer.jpg"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </template>

     </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently solved it by placing the snippet block's template to the snippets template itself. Apparently there is a problem with calling the subtemplate.

When I drag the snippet inside another snippet, I'm actually dragging the <t t-call="template_name"> tag into another snippet. It means that one cannot change the template right in where it is dragged but only by editing the subtemplate itself, which means that when it is dragged into some other template, the changes is inherited, and which is very unlikely expected.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings, and clear all those snippet things from particular view file.

> **Settings** -> **General Settings** -> **User Interface** -> **Views**

Then,

Find your

> **view** & **edit it**

.
Clear template code which you cant to clear.
Note : Before delete any section please correct one time it.